# How does the “eight day" appearance of Jesus to Doubting Thomas in John 20:26 relate to Parsha Shemini (Eighth Day) "appearance" Leviticus 9:1 & 10:2?

Tags: gospel-of-john, judaism, thomas-apostle, lectionary

I have been following Jewish and Christian lectionaries for some years and have often noticed interesting relationships.  Became aware of Aileen Gulding's work on this idea: [The Fourth Gospel and Jewish worship: a study of the relation of St. John's Gospel to the ancient Jewish lectionary system](https://www.worldcat.org/title/fourth-gospel-and-jewish-worship-a-study-of-the-relation-of-st-johns-gospel-to-the-ancient-jewish-lectionary-system/oclc/3058412).

Does "eighth day" references in Leviticus 9:1 and John 20:26 have connection.  Both readings involve "appearances" of God.

I am asking to consider connection between Parsha Shemini read 4/18/20 & Sunday's Gospel. https://www.chabad.org/parshah/default_cdo/aid/15576/jewish/Shemini.htm https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+20.19-31&version=RSV "9 On the eighth day Moses called Aaron" &  "26 Eight days later," respectively.  Other connections?  Doubt of Thomas?  "Guilt" of Nadav & Abihu? Thomas looks forward to Pentecost "Fire".77777 Weeks after Bush.  "22 And when he had said this, he breathed on them, and said to them, “Receive the Holy Spirit.John 20.22"  Nadav & Abihu look back to "Fire" at the Bush--77 Weeks earlier.  Counting Omer? "Bush Fire Ex 3.2 fire came forth Lv 10.2 . tongues as of fire Acts 2.2,"   http://biblechronologybooks.com/

Was Shemini Parsha read in synagogue the Sabbath Day before Jesus appearance on "eighth day" to Thomas?

"...Jews in Israel and Reform Jews celebrate Passover for seven days and thus read the next parashah  2018, Shemini) on the Sabbath one week after the first day of Passover, ...."

[Shemini (parsha)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemini_(parsha))

"...and she shows that many of the discourses
recorded in his gospel actually match the reading for the Sabbath in the Jewish lectionary system.
This is not as strange as it seems, for Jesus (the word made flesh) often used the occasion of the
Sabbath to demonstrate miracles or for exposition, it would be natural for him to base that on
the current reading...." https://www.biblaridion.info/Digressions/rev_feasts.pdf

Comment: Since Jesus rose on the first day of the week, the eighth day is the day of resurrection. The third say has spiritual meaning regarding resurrection and so does the eighth day. The eighth conveys that the first creation is seen as past and finished. A new creation begins on the first day of a new week.

Comment: From a Catholic point of view, I would think this question is quite answerable. Would that be acceptable to you Larry?

Comment: I am asking to consider connection between Parsha Shemini read 4/18/20 & Sunday's Gospel.